# No one vs No one else usage

Tags: adverbs

> 1. John is my best friend. **No one** likes me more than he does.
> 2. John is my best friend. **No one else** likes me more than he does.

1) Which is correct? What is the difference between these two sentences?

2)What is the basic difference between “no one” and “no one else” ?

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence is okay.

> John is my best friend. **No one** likes me **more than** he does.

You need not write **No one else** to exclude John from **No one** because *"John likes me more than he (John) likes me"* sounds unnatural and impossible.

But

> John is my best friend. **No one else** likes me **as much as** he does.

Here, You need to write **No one else** to exclude John from **No one** because *"John likes me as much as he likes me"* is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. "No one else" means no one, but with some person or group excluded. If that person or group is explicitly stated, it's redundant, but not wrong. Likewise, making a comparison implicitly excludes whatever you're comparing the rest to.

So when is it necessary? Usually when the exception has already been specified and needn't be repeated.

> John is my best friend. **No one else** likes me more.
>
> John is my best friend. **No one** likes me more **than he does.**

In the second example, we repeat the comparison, so "else" becomes redundant. In the first example, "else" is the only word that indicates what comparison is being made, so it's necessary.